# Height of a div 100% inside another div with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Here is a sample design (make the preview wide -- ideally 800px).
https://jsfiddle.net/Brunni/2n3w33g9/

Basically it's a bunch of divs nested with flex and everything works well until `container`. Then I have the `transitioner` div which serves for push-right-to-left transitions (I put two example `template-wrapper`s that are currently supposedly scrolling).

I don't understand why the `transitioner` div is computed as height=0. I guess children can not have a dependency on the parent since the parent is flowed depending on the children, but I couldn't find a statement that this is absolutely true.

Then things get worse since I need to absolute-position the `template-wrapper`s that will be animated. My ultimate goal is to have the `scroller`/`template-wrapper` to be 100% of the `container` even though they are `absolute`-positioned. Is that even possible?

Comment: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Comment: what want  excepted ?

Comment: Thanks!! That's actually the solution. I don't see how I didn't figure that. Anyway thank you a lot! How can we mark this as resolved?

For future reference, in my snippet you have to set `position:relative` on  `#container`, `position:absolute` on `.transitioner`, and then remove the `top:75px` on `.template-wrapper` and it works perfectly!